# Wrong H3 index from go library

Tags: go, h3

I'm currently trying to use uber H3 library to replace S2, but at the moment and with a couples of test it seems that the golang bindings doesn't give me back the right coords from a h3 index ...

when using the cmd line binaries with the same data that i use in the go app i don't get the same results.

With the cmd line tools:

```
λ  h3/bin master ✓ ./geoToH3 10
  46.810944 -71.241730
  8a2bac51621ffff
λ  h3/bin master ✓ ./h3ToGeo
  8a2bac51621ffff
  46.8105012488 -71.2410520551
λ  h3/bin master ✓ ./h3ToGeoBoundary
  8a2bac51621ffff
  8a2bac51621ffff
  {
    46.811170344 -71.240689900
    46.811037324 -71.241737545
    46.810368226 -71.242099684
    46.809832156 -71.241414199
    46.809965172 -71.240366583
    46.810634262 -71.240004422
  }
```

With Go:

```
cellLvl := 10
cellID := h3.FromGeo(h3.GeoCoord{Latitude: 46.810944, Longitude: -71.241730}, cellLvl)
```

I get this H3 index: `802bfffffffffff`
And those GeoBoundries:

```
[lat:50.77050266836529 lng:296.79922600446486  lat:48.295316381881364 lng:278.0803730010917  lat:37.09958889681994 lng:275.4148329679119  lat:30.219492199828103 lng:285.35953183291997  lat:31.87788595636582 lng:297.9774744521555  lat:40.97555819925587 lng:305.1209872207507 ]
```

Is it a known bug or there's something i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug, https://github.com/uber/h3-go/issues/7, just substract 360 from the longitude returned from h3 to make it work properly.

Comment: Note that this is fixed in the core C library in release 3.1.1, but `h3-go` is currently lagging behind the core lib.

Comment: Do you have any idea when it will be fixed ?

Comment: The primary maintainer for h3-go is out through the end of February :/